# Console not (generating?) displaying any items when I create/insert to database using sqflite

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, sqflite

I'm learning flutter, and the part of creating a database I used:

```
  void createDatabase() async {
    database = await openDatabase('MM.db', version: 1,
        onCreate: (database, version) async {
      print('DB ceated');
      await database
          .execute(
              'CREATE TABLE INFO (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Type TEXT, date TEXT)')
          .then((value) {
        print('DB createeed');
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("DB create error.${error.toString()}");
      }); //bec it returns FUTURE<void>
    }, onOpen: (databse) {
      print('DB opened');
    }); //Db name,version changes when we change the db structure,
  }
```

And to insert

```
  void insertToDatabase() {
    database?.transaction((txn) {
      txn
          .rawInsert(
              'INSERT INTO INFO(type, date) VALUES("Hello","1952022")')
          .then((value) {
        print(' $value inserted successfully');
      }).catchError((error) {
        print('error when inserting ${error.toString()}');
      });
throw '';
    });
```

When I run the program I expect the database to write 'DB createeeed' but nothing is displayed on the console, even if I set the main function to run the file that has that database code as the starting page

I've also linked the insertToDatabase function to a button where:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){insertToDatabase();}, child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 140, 52, 152),),),
```

But still there will no be no output in the console, thus I'm not sure if the database is created, or inserted to, is there something I did wrong?

Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5)
The sqflite version in the pubspec.yaml is:

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: ^2.0.2+1
```

Note that I tried error handeling before using `.this` on a diffrent file from the same application and it didn't give out any output whatsoever so I changed it to `throw`, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `catchError` function is on the `then` return,  it takes some working with it to understand.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation
Here is the official documentation about a language feature called cascade-notation that I believe might help you. to use it would result in code like:

```dart
      await database
          .execute(
              'CREATE TABLE INFO (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Type TEXT, date TEXT)')
          ..then((value) { // This line changed to ..
        print('DB createeed');
      })..catchError((error) { // This line changed to .. as well
        print("DB create error.${error.toString()}");
      });
```

This way you would get the errors on the actual `execute` function not the `then` function.

#### Edit

Sometimes, working with `then` it's a little confusing, so I usually avoid that. So, considering the `catchError` method returns only when the `onError` (function parameter passed) returns, what I would actually do:

```dart
      bool noError = true;
      await database.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE INFO (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Type TEXT, '
        'date TEXT)',
      ).catchError((error) {
        noError = false;
        print("DB create error.${error.toString()}");
      });
      if(noError) {
        print('DB createeed');
      }
```

Comment: It gives the error:
`This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.`
When I edit the createDatabase() function

Weirdly enough if I do this suggestion on the insertToDatabasee function however it won't give out that error. But I won't be able to check if it gives out any output since the createDatabase() function is not cascaded.

Comment: @Zeiad98 it's edited